# Is there a way in React to find all tags or classes of a certain type?

Tags: reactjs

I just want to do something simple like:

```
ReactDOM.find('img')
```

I can't seem to find anything in the documentation that does this. Do I just need to use jQuery? In my `componentDidMount` method, I want to add a listener to all `img` tags.

Comment: Is the downvote really necessary? Yes, there's `document.querySelectorAll` but I was wondering if there was an official React way of searching the DOM for specific selectors.

Comment: For reference, I didn't downvote — but why would there be a React way when a perfectly good one already exists in browsers?

Comment: Same reason jQuery has its own way of finding elements? Or any other framework has its own way of doing things differently from how the browser built-in way does.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` exists in the spec because of jQuery. Good frameworks don't reinvent the wheel when there are acceptable alternatives already.

Answer (score 0):

React does not have wrappers for convenient DOM access / DOM manipulation similar to jQuery because React recommends against having to access the DOM at all.

The DOM should be treated just as a rendering layer, not as a data store - your application state should entirely reside in javascript. Hence you never need to either access the DOM nor query it.

Comment: In this case I need to access and modify all IMGs in the component, so I do need some way to access/query the DOM.

Comment: No you don't. You just re-render with the updated state.

Comment: No :) I actually need to query the DOM because I'm adding listener events to the images, and doing some specific stuff that goes beyond rendering.